# How to save value Intent inside Calling API?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, retrofit2

I have a problem for saving value in Intent from calling API, the calling API showing its value, but i can't save it to intent.
this is my Code
Saving in Intent

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Intent mIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), KelasOnlineActivity.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("link",kelas.get(position).getUrl());
            sharedPrefKelas.saveSPString(SharedPrefKelas.SP_ID_Kelas, "");
            Call<Kelas> result = mApiInterface.KelasCall(kelas.get(position).getUrl(), sharedPrefManager.getSpIdMember(), sharedPrefManager.getSpLevelMember(), sharedPrefManager.getSpToken());
            result.enqueue(new Callback<Kelas>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Kelas> call, Response<Kelas> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        Kelas mkelas = response.body();
                        Log.d("data", "Nyoba Status Kelas: " + mkelas.statuschat);
                        mIntent.putExtra("Status",mkelas.statuschat);


                    } else {
                        Log.i("debug", "cekdata: GA BERHASIL");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Kelas> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("debug", "onFailure: ERROR > " + t.getMessage());

                }
            });

            mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            view.getContext().startActivity(mIntent);
```

[image]

Getting Intent

```
    Intent intent;
    intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    url= intent.getStringExtra("link");
    status = intent.getStringExtra("Status");

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), url+status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

i can display url in Toast but not the status, the status showing null,
This is the picture of the problem
[image]

Can anyone help me?I am grateful if anyone can solve my problem

Comment: You will not be able to see Status because, you're writing the line mIntent.putExtra("Status",mkelas.statuschat); inside, which means it will work on background and can take time to give response, hence before getting response your intent will get called.

Comment: oh, ok thanks bro, can u give me any reference that can solve how to save value from the calling API inside onclick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `startActivity` outside of `onResponse` callback: in this way, it'll call the new activity surely before onResponse, and surely before the status-save event.

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Intent mIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), KelasOnlineActivity.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("link",kelas.get(position).getUrl());  //This is outside of onResponse, so it's added correctly
            sharedPrefKelas.saveSPString(SharedPrefKelas.SP_ID_Kelas, "");
            Call<Kelas> result = mApiInterface.KelasCall(kelas.get(position).getUrl(), sharedPrefManager.getSpIdMember(), sharedPrefManager.getSpLevelMember(), sharedPrefManager.getSpToken());
            result.enqueue(new Callback<Kelas>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Kelas> call, Response<Kelas> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        Kelas mkelas = response.body();
                        Log.d("data", "Nyoba Status Kelas: " + mkelas.statuschat);
                        mIntent.putExtra("Status",mkelas.statuschat);

                        //You should put them here
                        mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                        view.getContext().startActivity(mIntent);

                    } else {
                        Log.i("debug", "cekdata: GA BERHASIL");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Kelas> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("debug", "onFailure: ERROR > " + t.getMessage());

                }
            });

            //And not here
            //mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            //view.getContext().startActivity(mIntent);
```

Comment: oh, ok thanks bro, but how i can save the value from calling API if the item are onclick? can u give me any reference that can solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you're asking, I can't understand what you want obtain

Comment: i want to obtain mkelas.statuschat bro, but i don't know how to save it and call it in another activity, i already use Sharedpref but it sometimes can't replace its key from its key before in Tab fragment

Comment: With my code you can access `statuschat` with `intent.getStringExtra("Status");` from another activity, then you can save it with `SharedPreferences` or whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

Try

```java
private String tmp = "";
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
     final Intent mIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), KelasOnlineActivity.class);
     mIntent.putExtra("link",kelas.get(position).getUrl());
     sharedPrefKelas.saveSPString(SharedPrefKelas.SP_ID_Kelas, "");
     Call<Kelas> result = mApiInterface.KelasCall(kelas.get(position).getUrl(), sharedPrefManager.getSpIdMember(), sharedPrefManager.getSpLevelMember(), sharedPrefManager.getSpToken());

     result.enqueue(new Callback<Kelas>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(Call<Kelas> call, Response<Kelas> response) {
              if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                  Kelas mkelas = response.body();
                  Log.d("data", "Nyoba Status Kelas: " + mkelas.statuschat);
                  tmp = mkelas.statuschat;
               } else {
                  Log.i("debug", "cekdata: GA BERHASIL");
               }
          }

          @Override
          public void onFailure(Call<Kelas> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("debug", "onFailure: ERROR > " + t.getMessage());
          }
            });

      mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      mIntent.putExtra("Status", tmp);
      view.getContext().startActivity(mIntent);
```

Comment: the value of status in Toast is "" bro same like tmp declare , its can't set the value inside  the calling api

Comment: sry bro my mistake, it's can show it's value but in the first click it didn't show its true value, need refresh before it showing the true value.